# SpriteKit scene not displaying correctly on iPad after switching to Universal App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, sprite-kit

So I had my SpriteKit game rendering nicely on both iPhone and iPad but I noticed that I was seeing the statusbar displaying on the iPad.  I went and checked that I had properly set the statusbar not to display correctly.  After a bit of searching I found a post that mentioned that in iOS7.1 the statusbar will display on an iPad unless you have it set to be a universal app.  Sure enough, I had mistakenly had my project set as a iPhone app.  I switched it to universal (and also elected not to have a separate storyboard created for iPad).  After that, the resolution for my scene was not displaying correctly on the iPad.  The app appears much larger now and goes off the screen.  My main sprite is supposed to follow my finger movement, but now it is way off to the right of where I swipe. Not sure what was done when I switched it to Universal, but switching it back now does not fix the problem.  It still renders fine on all iPhones, just not on the iPad anymore.  Has anyone else ran into this issue>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I did manage to get through the issue I was facing.  It looks like that because I was originally running on an iPad in iPhone mode, the UI made some assumptions that were incorrect for the device, I then made some tweaks in my code to compensate for this.  When I switched back to universal mode that through my "tweaks" out of wack.  I had my Scale Mode as SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit, and it still is, which I believe basically cut off my left and right sides slightly on the iPad (they were black) while running in iPhone mode and I couldn't figure out why I could not fill in those black spaces.  Now that I undid my tweaks and am using universal mode things are rendering correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller's viewDidLoad method change `scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;` To `scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;`

OR

Add these strings to Your info.plist file

```
Main storyboard file base name (iPhone)  yourStoryboard

Main storyboard file base name (iPad)    yourStoryboard
```

Good Luck

Comment: Just tried that, no effect.  I did some file compares to see what actually changed and in my project.pbxproj file there are several entries that were made when the Universal setting was put in they are all TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = "1,2";  If I remove all of those entries, it works fine on the iPad again, but the Project Target Deployment setting now says iPhone and the status bar is back on the iPad.  Very odd that it works for the iPad until I want to say that it should be Universal.

Comment: Adding the two entries to my plist file had no effect, which I guess makes sense because the app is still working so it was referencing the storyboard before, but its just scaled wrong on the iPad now.  Not the ideal solution, but if I was to leave it as an iPhone app, could it still be deployed to the iPad on the App Store?

Comment: What if you change the view controller size to free Form?